# using blockUI jquery not able to unblock

Tags: html, iframe, jquery-blockui

My web structure is

```
     Header-of-page
```

---

```
     Global-Iframe
```

iFrame for (LHS)|| Main contents of links will get open

Navigation Links  || in this another iFrame(lets say MainIframe)

---

```
   Footer
```

In MainIframe on click button I am getting some data from server side which take some time, so till my request get processed I have used block() of jquery blockUI plugin.

Once my request is processed my page is going to redirect to some other page. so on that document.ready I'm trying to unblock() but its not working.

Blocking by below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#btnConfirmRO').click(function() {
    //+
    // To display wait message.
    //

        $('#Global_iFrame',parent.document.body).block({ 
            message: 'Please wait!' ,
            css: {  
                    width: '70px', 
                    top: '5px', 
                    left: '2px', 
                    right: '2px', 
                    border: 'none', 
                    padding: '2px', 
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                    opacity: .6, 
                    color: '#000',

                    }
         }); 

    //
    //
    //-

});
```

});

Unblock:(After redirection)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 


$("#Global_iFrame").unblock(alert(' Calling Unblock UI')); 
});
```

Comment: Unrelated comment - the [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) form control is only supported by about half of the major desktop/mobile browsers, but it's worth getting familiar with. It's a native auto-complete, basically.

Comment: I haven't tried out blockUI, but based on your description, you are not going the right approach. First off, blocking is generally something to avoid whenever possible. Second, in your scenario you would want to block while the content area was loading and then unblock. Unblocking after a redirect doesn't make sense. Blocking/Unblocking is for ajax requests after the page is loaded, not something that carries over between page loads. If you are going to redirect anyway, why not have the page you redirect to handle the ajax request so that the redirect occurs when it's done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In my case , i'm using blockUI 2.6 version :

Block user interface or other elements:

```
BlockUI.Component(".page-content");
```

Then this is a working solution:

```
BlockUI.UnblockComponent(".page-content");
```